# Can I run a t-test or a linear regression model using percentile rank scores?

Tags: regression, t-test, quantiles

This might sound trivial, but for one single variable I have percentile rank scores for 100 observations. My sample is divided in 2 groups: 20 Observations are in the Group 1, and 80 in the Group 2.

Can I run a t-test to say if, on average, the Group 1 has higher percentile scores when compared with Group 2?

In addition, could I use the percentile rank scores in a regression model, to predict another outcome variable?

My fear is that using percentile rank scores in regression models or in t-tests might somehow be wrong.

Comment: Cross-posted on Statalist. Suggestions at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1363317-running-a-t-test-anova-regression-on-percentile-rank-scores